# How to convert or repackage a folder back into docx

Tags: microsoft-word, archiving, docx

I have uncompressed a docx file (say `file.docx`) using 7zip to `file/`. (or alternatively, changed extension to `.zip` then extracted it)

I modified some images inside `file\word\media\` and now i want to recompile/rebundle/repackage the folder into a docx file. I am using MS Office 2007.

How can i do that?

- I tried zipping it back, then changing extension to docx, didn't work - msword showed corrupted file error, tried restoring/fixing it, failed, then exited with error.

As for the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info); i am trying to edit all the selected images in the docx via some manipulation (like [magick](https://imagemagick.org/) *and* thereafter in gimp)

This question is *similar* in spirit to:

- [How to edit and save .docx file in winrar directly without extracting?](https://superuser.com/questions/1659398/how-to-edit-and-save-docx-file-in-winrar-directly-without-extracting)
- [Compress folder into MacBinary (.bin) format](https://superuser.com/questions/1267849/compress-folder-into-macbinary-bin-format)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To correctly re-zip an unzipped `.docx` file, be sure to follow
the following rules :

- Replace the files in their original folder
- Zip the *contents* of the folder and avoid the common error
  of zipping up the folder
- Use Zip (DEFLATE64) compression.

Comment: I suspect you mean DEFLATE64 instead of Base 64?

Comment: @Blackhawk: Yes, this is indeed the precise name.

Comment: Ah yes, the CONTENTS! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would clone the backup copy (you did make a backup, right?) and replace the files you modified directly in the DOCX "archive" instead of trying to fiddle with the extracted contents.

If you renamed your DOCX file as a ZIP, Windows Explorer can open it like a folder and you can do a limited level of editing directly with the archive.

Answer (score 1):

From: https://deparkes.co.uk/2016/12/23/how-word-files-store-images/

You may also need to update various XML files in the 'ZIP'. Excerpts from the page referred to:

"**The docx xml stores properties about the images.**

Within the ‘word’ folder in the unzipped docx document you’ll find document.xml which contains the structure of the document. Open this file up and you’ll see a series of ‘p’ – paragraph – elements which make up your document."

[image]

In this there are three p elements – one for each line of text and one for the image. In this case the image is the second of the paragraphs. We can explore the branches of this tree until we find “r:id” under “v:imagedata”.

[image]

Possibly the hex values are checksums? And if your modifications change for example dimensions and checksums, this may be what's causing the issues when opening the recompressed DOCX files.

I'll also include the URL to the video the page refers to: https://youtu.be/p9MqsEIHFXE

Comment: no, there is no problem with checksums, as i changed the images and it worked well (at least with MSO-W-2007). but thanks for digging deep 

Comment: @user8395964, feel free to upvote when it turns out to be step towards solution. and also mentioned dimensions. basically, the answer is just a means to dig deeper and determine what it is that upsets Word about your modified files.