# How to modify internal XML of PPTX files without corrupting them?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, zip, xml, pptx

I opened this question in SO site but it seems is more appropiate here.

Inside an `.pptx` file we have this structure

[image: Structure]

I'm trying to edit the content of internal `slide2.xml` in `..\ppt\slides`.

The `slide2.xml` content is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"><p:cSld><p:bg><p:bgPr><a:blipFill dpi="0" rotWithShape="1"><a:blip r:embed="rId2"><a:lum/></a:blip><a:srcRect/><a:stretch><a:fillRect/></a:stretch></a:blipFill><a:effectLst/></p:bgPr></p:bg><p:spTree><p:nvGrpSpPr><p:cNvPr id="1" name=""/><p:cNvGrpSpPr/><p:nvPr/></p:nvGrpSpPr><p:grpSpPr><a:xfrm><a:off x="0" y="0"/><a:ext cx="0" cy="0"/><a:chOff x="0" y="0"/><a:chExt cx="0" cy="0"/></a:xfrm></p:grpSpPr><p:sp><p:nvSpPr><p:cNvPr id="4" name="CuadroTexto 3"/><p:cNvSpPr txBox="1"/><p:nvPr/></p:nvSpPr><p:spPr><a:xfrm><a:off x="2701636" y="1249854"/><a:ext cx="14505709" cy="3053139"/></a:xfrm><a:prstGeom prst="rect"><a:avLst/></a:prstGeom><a:noFill/><a:ln w="12700" cap="flat"><a:noFill/><a:miter lim="400000"/></a:ln><a:effectLst/><a:sp3d/></p:spPr><p:style><a:lnRef idx="0"><a:scrgbClr r="0" g="0" b="0"/></a:lnRef><a:fillRef idx="0"><a:scrgbClr r="0" g="0" b="0"/></a:fillRef><a:effectRef idx="0"><a:scrgbClr r="0" g="0" b="0"/></a:effectRef><a:fontRef idx="none"/></p:style><p:txBody><a:bodyPr rot="0" spcFirstLastPara="1" vertOverflow="overflow" horzOverflow="overflow" vert="horz" wrap="square" lIns="48766" tIns="48766" rIns="48766" bIns="48766" numCol="1" spcCol="38100" rtlCol="0" anchor="t"><a:spAutoFit/></a:bodyPr><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr marL="0" marR="0" indent="0" algn="ctr" defTabSz="1300480" rtl="0" fontAlgn="auto" latinLnBrk="0" hangingPunct="0"><a:lnSpc><a:spcPct val="100000"/></a:lnSpc><a:spcBef><a:spcPts val="0"/></a:spcBef><a:spcAft><a:spcPts val="0"/></a:spcAft><a:buClrTx/><a:buSzTx/><a:buFontTx/><a:buNone/><a:tabLst/></a:pPr><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US" altLang="en-US" sz="9600" dirty="0"><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFBE00"/></a:solidFill><a:latin typeface="+mj-lt"/></a:rPr><a:t>Old text</a:t></a:r><a:br><a:rPr lang="en-US" altLang="en-US" sz="9600" dirty="0"><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFBE00"/></a:solidFill><a:latin typeface="+mj-lt"/></a:rPr></a:br><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US" altLang="en-US" sz="9600" dirty="0" err="1"><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="00C8FF"/></a:solidFill><a:latin typeface="+mj-lt"/></a:rPr><a:t>abc</a:t></a:r><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US" altLang="en-US" sz="9600" dirty="0"><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="00C8FF"/></a:solidFill><a:latin typeface="+mj-lt"/></a:rPr><a:t> Xyz</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr kumimoji="0" lang="es-ES_tradnl" sz="5400" b="0" i="0" u="none" strike="noStrike" cap="none" spc="0" normalizeH="0" baseline="0" dirty="0"><a:ln><a:noFill/></a:ln><a:solidFill><a:schemeClr val="bg1"/></a:solidFill><a:effectLst/><a:uFillTx/><a:latin typeface="+mn-lt"/><a:ea typeface="+mn-ea"/><a:cs typeface="+mn-cs"/><a:sym typeface="Calibri"/></a:endParaRPr></a:p></p:txBody></p:sp></p:spTree></p:cSld><p:clrMapOvr><a:masterClrMapping/></p:clrMapOvr><p:transition spd="med"/></p:sld>
```

I want to replace a little text inside `slide2.xml` from this:

```
...<a:t>Old text</a:t>...
```

to this:

```
...<a:t>New text</a:t>...
```

when I replace at least 1 letter and convert to `.zip` the whole folder and then change extension from `.zip` to `.pptx` and try to open the file, MS Powerpoint detects an error and tries to repair the file unsuccessfully.

I don't know why is happening this if I only change a few letters or even one letter. I've tried with bash command (sed) and manually with text editor.

Somebody knows how to edit/modify any `slideX.xml` without corrupting the whole pptx file?

Comment: Microsoft has openly documented the .pptx format. If you don't get a good answer here quickly, you might want to check the specification and see if you can figure this out for yourself. Maybe there's a checksum or cryptographic signature somewhere in the format, that you'll need to regenerate or disable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-pptx/

Comment: @Spiff thank you for your help. I'm checking the link your shared

Comment: Also see https://superuser.com/q/1784011/705502

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of zipping the folder again, try editing the `.zip` file directly with any tool that can do it, e.g. [7-zip](https://7-zip.org/) (right click on file -> **Edit**). Note that you need to close the editor fully in order for 7-zip to register the saved changes. That worked for me with LibreOffice.

The reason this method is better is because whatever metadata is stored in the file, it's preserved. And when you create a new `.zip`, some of `.pptx` standards may not be followed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try, since I need to replace some images in "/ppt/media/". The thing is I already have a bash script that does the job and I dont want to do it manually, the issue is that the pptx template I use to modify text and images has changed. Is a new template and I'm stuck for this issue and I don´t know why the file is being corrupted.

Comment: It works mixing your suggestion with what they do with `zip` command here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161905/adding-unzipped-files-to-a-zipped-folder